# Why is wordpress showing the title tag twice after adding title-tag theme support?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, page-title

In WordPress, `wp_title` is showing twice or output is twice.

I have added `add_theme_support('title-tag')` in *functions.php*.

**The website's head:**

```
<head> 
    <meta name="description" content=""> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <?php me_get_favicon(); ?> 
    <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title> 
</head>
```

Comment: What should I do to remove it

Comment: Show us your Header.php file

Comment: <head>       
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <?php me_get_favicon();  ?>
        <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>            
    </head>

Comment: What is the output? You have your title twice in the `<title>` tag ?

Comment: Somethimg like "Sample Site << Just another siteSample Site << Just another site" added twice

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the `<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>` in your header.php file if you've added `add_theme_support('title-tag')` to your functions.php file.

WordPress automatically adds the title tag with that function. So you're adding it manually AND you're telling WordPress to add a title tag. Remove the title tag from your header, since the function is actually a more recent and dynamic addition to the WordPress core.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag